# How to make aws aurora serverless v2 publicly accessible through cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to connect aws aurora serverless v2 with pgadmin or another postgres client.
I have deployed the resources using cloudformation and serverless framework.
This is my current yml configuration:

```
resources:
  Conditions:
    CreateProdResources: !Equals ["${self:provider.stage}", "prod"]
    CreateDevResources: !Not [!Equals ["${self:provider.stage}", "prod"]]
  Resources:
    VPC:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"
        EnableDnsHostnames: !If [CreateDevResources, true, false]
        EnableDnsSupport: !If [CreateDevResources, true, false]
        Tags:
          - Key: "Name"
            Value: ${self:custom.resources.vpcTag}
    InternetGateway:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
    VPCGatewayAttachment:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment"
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        InternetGatewayId: !Ref "InternetGateway"
    EIP:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::EIP"
      Properties:
        Domain: "vpc"
    Nat:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::NatGateway"
      Properties:
        AllocationId: !GetAtt "EIP.AllocationId"
        SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet

    PublicSubnet:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Select
          - 0
          - !GetAZs ${self:provider.region}
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/24"
    SubnetA:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Select
          - 1
          - !GetAZs ${self:provider.region}
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.1.0/24"
    SubnetB:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Select
          - 2
          - !GetAZs ${self:provider.region}
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.2.0/24"
    PublicSubnetA:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Select
          - 1
          - !GetAZs ${self:provider.region}
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.3.0/24"
    PublicSubnetB:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Select
          - 2
          - !GetAZs ${self:provider.region}
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.4.0/24"

    RouteTable:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
    InternetRoute:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
      Properties:
        DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
        GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
    PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet
    PublicSubnetARouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetA
    PublicSubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetB

    NatRouteTable:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
    NatRoute:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
      Properties:
        DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
        NatGatewayId: !Ref "Nat"
        RouteTableId: !Ref "NatRouteTable"
    SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref NatRouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
    SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref NatRouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB

    InstanceSecurityGroup:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
      Properties:
        GroupName: "SecurityGroup"
        GroupDescription: "SecurityGroup"
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        SecurityGroupEgress:
          - IpProtocol: "-1"
            CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
    InstanceSecurityGroupIngress:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
      DependsOn: "InstanceSecurityGroup"
      Properties:
        GroupId: !Ref "InstanceSecurityGroup"
        IpProtocol: "tcp"
        FromPort: "0"
        ToPort: "65535"
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref "InstanceSecurityGroup"

    DBSubnetGroup:
      Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
      Properties:
        DBSubnetGroupName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-dbsubnetgroup
        DBSubnetGroupDescription: "${self:service}-dbsubnetgroup"
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref "SubnetA"
          - !Ref "SubnetB"
    PublicDBSubnetGroup:
      Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        DBSubnetGroupName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-publicdbsubnetgroup
        DBSubnetGroupDescription: "${self:service}-publicdbsubnetgroup"
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref "PublicSubnetA"
          - !Ref "PublicSubnetB"
    RDSCluster:
      Type: "AWS::RDS::DBCluster"
      Properties:
        MasterUsername: ${self:custom.resources.databaseUser}
        MasterUserPassword: ${self:custom.resources.databasePassword}
        DatabaseName: ${self:custom.resources.databaseName}
        Engine: "aurora-postgresql"
        EngineVersion: "14.3"
        ServerlessV2ScalingConfiguration:
          MinCapacity: 0.5
          MaxCapacity: 2
        VpcSecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref "InstanceSecurityGroup"
        DBSubnetGroupName: !If [CreateDevResources, !Ref "PublicDBSubnetGroup", !Ref "DBSubnetGroup"]
    DBInstance1:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      Properties:
        DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref "RDSCluster"
        DBInstanceClass: db.serverless
        Engine: aurora-postgresql
    DBInstance2:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      Properties:
        DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref "RDSCluster"
        DBInstanceClass: db.serverless
        Engine: aurora-postgresql
```

Reading aws [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html), as it says, I'm adding vpc dns hostnames and support, 2 public subnets and a public dbsubnetgroup if environment is for development, but still can't connect database with pgadmin, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mark's answer I made this work with some tweaks.

First of all added MapPublicIpOnLaunch to public subnets, added securitygroupingress rule to allow all traffic and finally added PubliclyAccessible property not to the cluster, which for some reason doesnt work, but to all the db instances.

So the the resources ended like this:

```
resources:
  Conditions:
    CreateProdResources: !Equals ["${self:provider.stage}", "prod"]
    CreateDevResources: !Not [!Equals ["${self:provider.stage}", "prod"]]
  Resources:
    VPC:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"
        EnableDnsHostnames: !If [CreateDevResources, true, false]
        EnableDnsSupport: !If [CreateDevResources, true, false]
        Tags:
          - Key: "Name"
            Value: ${self:custom.resources.vpcTag}
    InternetGateway:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
    VPCGatewayAttachment:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment"
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        InternetGatewayId: !Ref "InternetGateway"
    EIP:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::EIP"
      Properties:
        Domain: "vpc"
    Nat:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::NatGateway"
      Properties:
        AllocationId: !GetAtt "EIP.AllocationId"
        SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet

    PublicSubnet:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Select
          - 0
          - !GetAZs ${self:provider.region}
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/24"
    SubnetA:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Select
          - 1
          - !GetAZs ${self:provider.region}
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.1.0/24"
    SubnetB:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: !Select
          - 2
          - !GetAZs ${self:provider.region}
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.2.0/24"
    PublicSubnetA:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
        AvailabilityZone: !Select
          - 1
          - !GetAZs ${self:provider.region}
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.3.0/24"
    PublicSubnetB:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
        AvailabilityZone: !Select
          - 2
          - !GetAZs ${self:provider.region}
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.4.0/24"

    RouteTable:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
    InternetRoute:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
      Properties:
        DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
        GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
    PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet
    PublicSubnetARouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetA
    PublicSubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetB

    NatRouteTable:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
    NatRoute:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
      Properties:
        DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
        NatGatewayId: !Ref "Nat"
        RouteTableId: !Ref "NatRouteTable"
    SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref NatRouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
    SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref NatRouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB

    InstanceSecurityGroup:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
      Properties:
        GroupName: "SecurityGroup"
        GroupDescription: "SecurityGroup"
        VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
        SecurityGroupEgress:
          - IpProtocol: "-1"
            CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
    InstanceSecurityGroupIngress:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
      DependsOn: "InstanceSecurityGroup"
      Properties:
        GroupId: !Ref "InstanceSecurityGroup"
        IpProtocol: "tcp"
        FromPort: "0"
        ToPort: "65535"
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref "InstanceSecurityGroup"
    PublicInstanceSecurityGroupIngress:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
      DependsOn: "InstanceSecurityGroup"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        GroupId: !Ref "InstanceSecurityGroup"
        IpProtocol: "-1"
        CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"

    DBSubnetGroup:
      Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
      Properties:
        DBSubnetGroupName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-dbsubnetgroup
        DBSubnetGroupDescription: "${self:service}-dbsubnetgroup"
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref "SubnetA"
          - !Ref "SubnetB"
    PublicDBSubnetGroup:
      Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
      Condition: CreateDevResources
      Properties:
        DBSubnetGroupName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-publicdbsubnetgroup
        DBSubnetGroupDescription: "${self:service}-publicdbsubnetgroup"
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref "PublicSubnetA"
          - !Ref "PublicSubnetB"
    RDSCluster:
      Type: "AWS::RDS::DBCluster"
      Properties:
        MasterUsername: ${self:custom.resources.databaseUser}
        MasterUserPassword: ${self:custom.resources.databasePassword}
        DatabaseName: ${self:custom.resources.databaseName}
        Engine: "aurora-postgresql"
        EngineVersion: "14.3"
        ServerlessV2ScalingConfiguration:
          MinCapacity: 0.5
          MaxCapacity: 2
        VpcSecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref "InstanceSecurityGroup"
        DBSubnetGroupName: !If [CreateDevResources, !Ref "PublicDBSubnetGroup", !Ref "DBSubnetGroup"]
    DBInstance1:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      Properties:
        DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref "RDSCluster"
        DBInstanceClass: db.serverless
        PubliclyAccessible: !If [CreateDevResources, true, false]
        Engine: aurora-postgresql
    DBInstance2:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      Properties:
        DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref "RDSCluster"
        DBInstanceClass: db.serverless
        PubliclyAccessible: !If [CreateDevResources, true, false]
        Engine: aurora-postgresql
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `PubliclyAccessible: true` flag on the `RDSCluster`. The DB only gets a public IP address when that flag is set to `true`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, currently deploying with publiclyaccessible flag true, although cloudformation docs says:
If DBSubnetGroupName is specified, and PubliclyAccessible isn't specified, the following applies:
If the subnets are part of a VPC that has an internet gateway attached to it, the DB cluster is public.

Shouldn't my current configuration make the cluster public?

Comment: Can you link to that documentation? I've never found that to be true. I've always had to enable the flag to make it public.

Comment: Also note that you will have to make sure `EnableDnsHostnames` and `EnableDnsSupport` are set to `true` on the VPC for the RDS cluster to be public.  That's mentioned in the documentation you linked in your question. I can't tell if you are setting those to `true` since you have a condition on those fields.

Comment: This is the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-publiclyaccessible

Comment: update: deploy failed with the error: PubliclyAccessible isn't supported for DB engine aurora-postgresql

Comment: That documentation seems at least partially wrong. It doesn't even make sense, because what would be the point of the `PubliclyAccessible` flag if just moving it to the public subnets caused it to be public? Even with `PubliclyAccessible=true` the cluster also needs to be in public subnets to be accessible publicly. The `PubliclyAccessible` flag is basically the same thing as `AssignPublicIP` on EC2 instances, and without that enabled, just being in a public subnet isn't enough to make something public.

Comment: As for your error, I'm pretty sure I've seen Aurora PostgreSQL clusters that were publicly accessible before. I think it may be blocking you because you have some serverless nodes in the cluster. I would try change the flag from the AWS web console to see if it gives you any better error message. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70010919/cant-make-aws-aurora-postgres-rds-publicly-available for someone that says at the end they got an Aurora PostgreSQL server to be publicly accessible.